# How do I download a file from an unknown location?

Tags: c#, xml, download

I have a problem I have been trying to solve, but can't seem to find the answer, so hopefully someone here can help me find an answer.

The problem is that I am trying to create a web-scrape from a website that dynamically generates a download file. The website requires various parameters to be entered in order to classify your data request. Once you hit the submit button, the website dynamically generates the data request according to your parameters and downloads the result in a file. This works fine in a browser.

When trying to do this with C#, my code successfully submits the request with the desired parameters and catches the HTML response, but cannot seem to catch the file download response. The file download location at the remote URL is masked. The download filename is dynamically generated with the format "Inquiry_currentdate_currenttime.xml". The filesize can vary depending upon the data request being submitted.

This remote URL is pushing the data file to me rather than me pulling the data from the URL using c# DownloadFile. How would I catch this "pushed" file?

The code I have tried so far is below. This code successfully submits the request and gets an Html response.

```
    foreach (string fy in lstFY)
    {
      foreach (string st in lstState)
      {
        HtmlHandler b = new HtmlHandler();
        b.Get(gWebTgtName);
        b.FormElements["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlFundingYear"] = fy;
        b.FormElements["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$ddlState"] = st;
        //set reporting format (XML)      radiobutton
        b.FormElements["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$rblReportFormat"] = "xml";
        //set "select data points"        ckbx
        b.FormElements["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$cbSelectDatapoints"] = "on";
        //set "select All Data Points"    ckbx
        b.FormElements["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$cbAll"] = "on";
        //set "submit button"
        b.FormElements["ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder$bSearch"] = "Build Data File!";
        //SUBMIT (build data file)
        string resp3 = b.Post(gWebTgtName);
        //RESPONSE
        //save XMLfile
        //process XMLfile
      }
    }


    public string Post(string url)
    {
      _isPost = true;
      CreateWebRequestObject().Load(url, "POST");
      return _htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;
    }
    private HtmlWeb CreateWebRequestObject()
    {
      HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
      web.UseCookies = true;
      web.PreRequest = new HtmlWeb.PreRequestHandler(OnPreRequest);
      web.PostResponse = new HtmlWeb.PostResponseHandler(OnAfterResponse);
      web.PreHandleDocument = new HtmlWeb.PreHandleDocumentHandler(OnPreHandleDocument);
      return web;
    }
    protected bool OnPreRequest(HttpWebRequest rqst)
    {
      AddCookiesTo(rqst);               // Add cookies that were saved from previous requests
      if (_isPost) AddPostDataTo(rqst); // We only need to add post data on a POST request
      return true;
    }
    protected void OnAfterResponse(HttpWebRequest rqst, HttpWebResponse resp)
    {
      SaveCookiesFrom(resp); // Save cookies for subsequent requests
      GetDownload(DRTCollector.gWebTgtName);

      string sWebPage = string.Empty;
      // get correct charset and encoding from the server's header
      string sCharset = resp.CharacterSet;
      Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(sCharset);
      // read response
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
      {
        sWebPage = sr.ReadToEnd();
        // Close and clean up the StreamReader
        sr.Close();
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(sWebPage);
      }
    }
    private void AddCookiesTo(HttpWebRequest rqst)
    {
      if (Cookies != null && Cookies.Count > 0)
      {
        rqst.CookieContainer.Add(Cookies);
      }
    }
    private void AddPostDataTo(HttpWebRequest rqst)
    {
      string payload = FormElements.AssemblePostPayload();
      byte[] buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload.ToCharArray());
      rqst.ContentLength = buff.Length;

      rqst.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      rqst.Accept = "image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5";

      //rqst.ContentType = "application/xml";
      //rqst.Accept = "application/xml";

      System.IO.Stream reqStream = rqst.GetRequestStream();
      reqStream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what have you tried?

Comment: Put some snippet of the code, that you currently have for better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Depending on how the web site works, the download might be available only for the same session that asked for it to be created. If that's the case, you'll need to catch the session cookie returned by the server, and send it back again when you download the file.

Comment: The remote website is known to be aspx.net, running on IIS6. That is interesting about the cookie idea. I will look into that.

Comment: I have tried various contenttypes, modifying the request, searched for other various download methods where one would not know the remote file location and possibly the final downloaded filename. I know that other commercial products are able to catch files as well as browsers do. I wanted to be able to do the same without using a browser. Since I cannot locate that method, I will use the built-in browser within Selenium to achieve my goals. Thanks also to Marcus and @steavy for the help attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having any code to better describe what you're doing, I would say try using Selenium or some other (Web UI testing tool to generate test code and review its functionality. With some Fiddler session data, should be able to RE the process. Selenium is nice bc it will generate test code in several languages, including C# (and bc its free). HTH

Comment: Paully, I have posted the code above. I have done the tracing with Fiddler. This helped with getting the parameter strings entered correctly. I will look into Selenium.

Comment: Great- if it helps, give me some love!

Comment: Initially, I was hoping to "catch" the downloaded file in a similar manner done by a browser, but by using Selenium's built-in browser, I will be able to utilize that to achieve the goal of obtaining the downloaded file(s). Thanks for the pointers to a useful tool.